# How to solve this below issue?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

I have a background service and i am doing some long running task. Based on some conditions i am showing AlertDialog to the user . I have used AppCompatButton in that alert dialog layout. Will it cause any issue like mentioned below. What is the way to solve it.

```
View class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).
```

Answer (score 1):

That means your app theme must inherit from one of ***Theme.AppCompat*** themes. Go to ***themes.xml*** (or ***styles.xml*** if it's an older project), check the ***parent*** field of your theme, and change it with one of Theme.AppCompat themes:
ex: Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (any other theme that inherits from Theme.AppCompat could work as well)